# Links jump to top and bottom but smooth scrolling doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Links jump to bottom and top but won't smooth scroll even though I'm sure JS is working.

JS:

```
$.fn.ready(function() {

            // Smooth scroll to top.
            $("a[href=#top]").live("click", function(e) {
                $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000);
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            // Smooth scroll to bottom.
            $("a[href=#bot]").live("click", function(e) {
                $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 1000);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
 <a href="#bot" id="botlink" title="Go to bottom">↓</a>
 <a href="#top" id="toplink" title="Go to top">↑</a>
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9 you should consider using `.on()` if your version is 1.7 or higher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using an old version of jQuery if you use "live" event. 
Since you want to go on top/bottom, you know that they're on certain positions ( top = 0, bottom = document.height ). A working jquery code will be like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $('#botlink').add( $('#toplink') ).on( 'click', function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $btn = $(this).attr( 'id' ).replace('#', '');
    var move_to = $btn === 'botlink' ? $(document).height() : 0;

    $('body').animate({
      scrollTop : move_to
    }, 'slow');

  });

});
```

The code above checks when user clicks `#botlink` or `toplink`. Inside `move_to` variable it checks which button was clicked ( read about "short if" ) and calculate when page should go. <del>To have a working effect, you need to animate both, `html` and `body`.</del>

Actuall it works just on `body`. You also have a js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vh6uot3z/) (i've foced body to grow on 1200px to be able to see the effect)

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle it might help you

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/h697225v/6/)

```
$("a[href=#top]").on("click", function (e) {
    //alert("top")
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': 0
    }, 1000)
    event.preventDefault();
});

// Smooth scroll to bottom.
$("a[href=#bot]").on("click", function (e) {
    // alert("bottom")
    var a = $(document).height()
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop': a + 'px'
    }, 1000)
    event.preventDefault();
});
```